# Index match and return multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm really struggling with this one. I have two worksheets. In worksheet 1 I have a list of case reference numbers in column A and peoples identification numbers in column B.

In worksheet 2 I have a list of the peoples identification numbers in column A and in column H I would like a formula that checks the personal identification number in say cell A2 and finds ALL the matches in column A (case reference numbers in sheet 1 and list them ALL (ideally a drop down menu) - but if not, columns h2-k2.

I've tried all sorts from the internet but I'm totally stumped :(

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried?

Comment: My index match formula is: =INDEX('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!A:A,MATCH(SUSPECTS!$A2,'OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B,0))  but this only returns the first result, in some cases there are multiple results (I would like to enter my formula in H2. I've tried variations of this formula too.....=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($A$9,$A$1:$A$7)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW($C$1:$C$7))),"",INDEX($A$1:$C$7,SMALL(IF(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($A$9,$A$1:$A$7)),FALSE,TRUE),ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW($C$1:$C$7)),3))

Comment: YAY!! I think i've cracked the basic formula (somehow!) - =INDEX('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$A:$A, SMALL(INDEX(($A$2='OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B)*(MATCH(ROW('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B), ROW($A:$A)))+($A$2<>'OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B)*1048577, 0, 0), COLUMN(A3))) trouble is, how to i drag this formula down or do I have to individually alter every line separately?

Comment: You should be able to drag it down using the small box in the bottom right of the cell when you've selected it.

If you've answered your own question, post it as an answer and you can accept it. It may help others in the future :)

Comment: Will do, finding this all quite addictive! :)

Answer (score 0):

YAY!! I think i've cracked the basic formula (somehow!) -

```
=INDEX('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$A:$A, SMALL(INDEX(($A$2='OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B)*(MATCH(ROW('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B), ROW($A:$A)))+($A$2<>'OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B)*1048577, 0, 0), COLUMN(A3)))
```

:) :) feeling accomplished!

Answer (score -1):

I just formatted the *loli*'s self answer (with removing 1 pair of redundant parentheses):

```
=INDEX(
    'OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$A:$A,
     SMALL(
         INDEX(
             ($A$2='OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B) 
             * MATCH(
                   ROW('OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B), 
                   ROW($A:$A)
               )
             + ($A$2<>'OUTSTANDING INVESTIGATIONS'!$B:$B) * 1048577, 
             0, 0
         ), 
         COLUMN(A3)
     )
 )
```

and for people who don't know:

> Yes, copy / paste this multi-row formula directly to the Excel cell perfectly works.

**Note:**

For manually writing a multi-row formula to the cell press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of individual rows.

Comment: @Ramhound - Because: **1**) I have not enough reputation to modify others' people answer without their consent -  **2**) Information in my answer can be new and useful for some people - **3**) To make simpler comparision if unformated and formatted formulas are both simultaneously displayed. - **Thank you for your question** - it's my fault that I didn't explain these reasons directly in my answer.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm sure you think so. May I ask you to kindly provide me with the link to the appropriate rule? Frankly, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thank you, it is nice from you to admit that I didn't broke some rule. - I already explained my reasons and I have neither power, nor motivation to convince you if you suppose something different. It's your right.

Comment: It's not a rule, it's more a standard, just done so it again.  It won't result on reputation.  Honestly I am just to lazy to find the meta question that explains it....

Comment: I don't suppose any one is able to help me with the next bit? I've got my formula in columns H-O. Is there any way that I can display a drop down list of all the results in say column G?